# ODOO8: Untaxed and total amount in order lines not calculating

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I add multiple PRODUCTS in the order lines of the REPAIR-ORDER, the price of each product shows up - but the untaxed sub total and total display (0) instead of the total of all products.

[image: TOTAL AMOUNT]
[image: UNTAXED AMOUNT]

I've attached some of the code of the MRP REPAIR (.py) file :

```
def _amount_all_wrapper_repair(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    """ Wrapper because of direct method passing as parameter for function fields """
    return self._amount_all_repair(cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=context)

def _amount_all_repair(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    cur_obj = self.pool.get('res.currency')
    res = {}
    for order in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        res[order.id] = {
            'amount_untaxed': 0.0,
            'amount_tax': 0.0,
            'amount_total': 0.0,
        }
        val = val1 = 0.0
        cur = order.sale_id.pricelist_id.currency_id
        for line in order.order_line_ids:
            val1 += line.price_subtotal
            val += self._amount_line_tax_repair(cr, uid, line, context=context)
        res[order.id]['amount_tax'] = cur_obj.round(cr, uid, cur, val)
        res[order.id]['amount_untaxed'] = cur_obj.round(cr, uid, cur, val1)
        res[order.id]['amount_total'] = res[order.id]['amount_untaxed'] + res[order.id]['amount_tax']
    return res
```

The code for the mrp_repair.xml:

```
<group class="oe_subtotal_footer oe_right" colspan="2" name="sale_total">
                            <field name="amount_untaxed" widget='monetary' options="{'currency_field': 'currency_id'}"/>
                            <field name="amount_tax" widget='monetary' options="{'currency_field': 'currency_id'}"/>
                            <div class="oe_subtotal_footer_separator oe_inline">
                                <label for="amount_total" />
                                <button name="button_dummy"
                                    states="draft,sent" string="(update)" type="object" class="oe_edit_only oe_link"/>
                            </div>
                            <field name="amount_total" nolabel="1" class="oe_subtotal_footer_separator" widget='monetary' options="{'currency_field': 'currency_id'}"/>
                            <div class="oe_inline" groups="garage.group_display_margin">
                                <label for="margin" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
                            </div>
                                <field name="margin" nolabel="1" style="font-weight:bold;" groups="garage.group_display_margin"/>

                        </group>
```

## EDIT - Added info

I found that without the code below (this code causes MRP_REPAIR to add order lines both to the REPAIR ORDER and SALES ORDER), adding a product with a price doesnt get calculated in total field, and shows zero (0)

```
        elif this.repair_sale_order_line_id:

            sale_obj = self.pool.get('sale.order')
            so_vals = {
                'partner_id' : this.repair_sale_order_line_id.partner_id.id,
                'fleet_id': this.repair_sale_order_line_id.fleet_id.id,
                'responsable_id': uid,

            }
            created_so_id = so_obj.create(cr, uid, so_vals, context=context)
            sol_vals = {'order_id': created_so_id,
                       'price_unit': this.price_unit,
                       'product_uom_qty': this.product_uom_qty,
                       'price_subtotal': this.price_subtotal,
                       'discount': this.discount,
                       'product_id': this.product_id.id,
                       'tax_id': [(6, 0, [x.id for x
                                                 in this.tax_id])],
                       'name': this.name,
                       }
            self.pool.get('mrp.repair').write(cr, uid, this.repair_sale_order_line_id.id, {'sale_id':created_so_id},context=context)
            sol_id = sol_obj.create_sol(cr, uid, sol_vals, context)
            super(repair_sale_order_line, self).write(cr, uid, [res],{'sale_order_line_id':sol_id})
```

it seems that the Sale Order lines are used instead of the internal Repair Sale Order lines. The question is: how can i make the mrp not depend on the SO or its ORDER LINES.?

Comment: Old API function fields are computed on save only. If you want to have them computed like on_change fields, either add some on_change behaviour (that will only do something in the views, because the fields are computed on save anyway) or change the fields to new API computed fields instead (on_change included).

Comment: Check the edit on the top of the page: thanks

Comment: What can be done to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found that without the code below (this code causes MRP_REPAIR to add order lines both to the REPAIR ORDER and SALES ORDER), adding a product with a price doesnt get calculated in total field, and shows zero (0)

```
        elif this.repair_sale_order_line_id:

            sale_obj = self.pool.get('sale.order')
            so_vals = {
                'partner_id' : this.repair_sale_order_line_id.partner_id.id,
                'fleet_id': this.repair_sale_order_line_id.fleet_id.id,
                'responsable_id': uid,

            }
            created_so_id = so_obj.create(cr, uid, so_vals, context=context)
            sol_vals = {'order_id': created_so_id,
                       'price_unit': this.price_unit,
                       'product_uom_qty': this.product_uom_qty,
                       'price_subtotal': this.price_subtotal,
                       'discount': this.discount,
                       'product_id': this.product_id.id,
                       'tax_id': [(6, 0, [x.id for x
                                                 in this.tax_id])],
                       'name': this.name,
                       }
            self.pool.get('mrp.repair').write(cr, uid, this.repair_sale_order_line_id.id, {'sale_id':created_so_id},context=context)
            sol_id = sol_obj.create_sol(cr, uid, sol_vals, context)
            super(repair_sale_order_line, self).write(cr, uid, [res],{'sale_order_line_id':sol_id})
```

it seems that the Sale Order lines are used instead of the internal Repair Sale Order lines. The question is: how can i make the mrp not depend on the SO or its ORDER LINES.?